setWindowIcon() in Qt6 fails only when running from one specific folder
I have a Qt6 application called acquisition that fails to set the window icon, but only when it's run from its installation directory in %LocalAppData%\Programs\acquisition.
If I copy the program folder out of %LocalAppData%\Programs to anywhere else, the window icon is set properly. I can even copy it to another subdirectory of %AppDataLocal%\Programs and it works.
(Acquisition also runs on macOS and Linux, but I'm not having this issue on those platforms).
I've found Stack Overflow questions about setting window icons in Qt, such as 69317555 and 29284643. The one that comes closest is 6523039, which suggests using the native Windows API and Qt5's winextras.
Overall, none of the answers I've found seem to apply because my window icon is properly set... unless I run the program from one specific installation directory. I suspect something like an environment variable or registry setting, but I can't find anything obvious.
Here is a minimally reproducible example:

The build environment is Qt Creator 13.0.2 with Qt 6.5.3.
The OS is Windows 11 version 23H2.
I'm using windeployqt (details below)
I've used Inno Setup 6 to build an installer in the past, but the problem is reproducible without this step now.

NOTE: This example uses an SVG icon. I've used QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS to confirm the SVG plug is loading, but the location-specific failure to set the window icon persists if I switch to a PNG icon.
Project files:
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
resources.qrc
deploy.cmd
assets/icon.svg

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.1)

project(acquisition)

find_package(Qt6 6.5.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Gui
    Svg
    Widgets
)

qt_standard_project_setup()

qt_add_executable(acquisition WIN32
    main.cpp
    resources.qrc
)

set_target_properties(acquisition PROPERTIES AUTORCC TRUE)

target_link_libraries(acquisition PUBLIC
    Qt::Core
    Qt::Gui
    Qt::Svg
    Qt::Widgets
)

main.cpp:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QDir>
#include <QIcon>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDialog dialog;
    dialog.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/assets/icon.svg"));
    dialog.show();

    return app.exec();
}

resources.qrc:
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC>
    <qresource>
        <file>assets/icon.svg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>

After making a Release build, I'm running windeployqt with a batch file.
deploy.cmd:
set "WINDEPLOYQT=C:\Qt\6.5.3\msvc2019_64\bin\windeployqt.exe"

set "BUILD_DIR=.\build\Desktop_Qt_6_5_3_MSVC2019_64bit-Release"
set "DEPLOY_DIR=%BUILD_DIR%\deploy";

rmdir /S /Q "%DEPLOY_DIR%"
mkdir "%DEPLOY_DIR%"

copy "%BUILD_DIR%\acquisition.exe" "%DEPLOY_DIR%"

"%WINDEPLOYQT%" "%DEPLOY_DIR%\acquisition.exe" --release --no-compiler-runtime --dir "%DEPLOY_DIR%"

At this point, if I run acquisition from the directory where I ran windeployqt, the window icon is set correctly. If I copy this folder to %LocalAppData%\Programs\acquisition and run it, the window icon is not set correctly. If I copy it to %LocalAppData%\Programs\acquisition_copy it works.
What is causing this issue?

Run with QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS env var set and see from where/if the svg iconengine plugin is loaded. I would guess it gets not deployed with windeployqt. You might also set QT_WIN_DEBUG_CONSOLE to a reasonable value if your app is a gui-only (without console) app.

@chehrlic, Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the output from QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS shows that the svg plugin is being loaded correctly. This oddball problem also shows up if I use a png icon.
Now I'm figuring out how to embed an icon directly into the executable, hopefully bypassing the need to use setWindowIcon() at all, at least on Windows.
